# Modifying script with sep. Inconsistent behaviour

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am trying to eliminate the <..>  tags out of this small script (its name is `test`):

```
<chan‌​ges><comment>Testing

Comment

Footer
</comment></chan‌​ges>
```

Whevener I try with `cat test | sed -e "s/<\/comment>//g; s/<comment>/ /g" > test1`,

the output is correct:

```
<chan‌​ges> Testing

Comment

Footer
</chan‌​ges>
```

But when I try `cat test | sed -e "s/<\/changes>//g; s/<changes>/ /g" > test1`, the script stays unchanged.

I have copy/pasted every command on the shell and tested it before putting it here, so I believe it is not a matter of typos.

Anyone knows what kind of dark magic this is?

Comment: there are some weird characters in your `changes` text. If I copy it I see `chan<200c><200b>ges`.

Comment: Looks like XML. Is it XML? Because if it is, you should use a parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you want to convert:

```
<chan‌​ges><comment>Testing

Comment

Footer
</comment></chan‌​ges>
```

To:

```
<chan‌​ges>Testing

Comment

Footer
</chan‌​ges>
```

You can use `(?:<(comment)>)(.*)(?:<\/\1>)` and replace to `\2`
https://regex101.com/r/rC1rP6/1

***Edit: Simpler regex and sed example:***

```
cat test | sed 's/<\/\?comment>//g
```

Replace `comment` with `chan‌​ges` to match other balise.

**Notice:** The reason you failed is because `changes` is written with an unicode character:

- `cat test | xxd` shows:

  ```
  0000000: 3c63 6861 6ee2 808c e280 8b67 6573 3e3c  <chan......ges><
  ```
- when `echo '<changes>' | xxd` shows:

  ```
  0000000: 3c63 6861 6e67 6573 3e0a                 <changes>.
  ```

Comment: I am aware there are lots of possibilities to improve the regex, but what I want is to delete `</changes>`, `<comment>` and `</comment>` already get replaced with the current command. The regex tool is great, though. Thanks for that

Comment: You are right, the original text is written in unicode. +1 for explaining how to see that.

Comment: You want to avoid the [useless `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html), too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm of the opinion that the correct tool for the job is *not* a regex. Because one thing regex isn't very good at is tag matching. I would instead suggest using a parser - this is a perl snippet that'll do what you require:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

print XML::Twig -> parse ( \*DATA ) -> get_xpath('//*',0) -> text;

__DATA__
<changes><comment>Testing

Comment

Footer
</comment></changes>
```

NB - had to clean your source data, which had some odd characters when I copied and pasted, which may actually be the root of your problem.

This you could one liner as:

```
perl -MXML::Twig -0777 'print XML::Twig->parse(<>)->get_xpath('//*',0)->text;' you_xml_filename
```

(Or it'll accept input on a pipe).

For more complicated scenarios, this won't work quite as well, but it's pretty trivial to adapt to a more general tag-stripping:

E.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

print map { $_ -> text } XML::Twig -> parse ( \*DATA ) -> get_xpath('//#PCDATA');

__DATA__
<changes><comment>Testing

Comment

Footer
</comment>
<anothercomment>fish here
</anothercomment>
<some_other_tag an_attribute="some_attribute">More text here</some_other_tag>
</changes>
```

([`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/Twig.pm) may need installing. This should be as simple as `cpan XML::Twig` or using your package manager)